# Use render layers in sequence editor

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, render-layers

I rendered an animation with different layers (3), and safed every frame as exr.
If I render just one frame I can see the every single layer using the "Render layers" node.

But if I render the whole animation, and then open all the exrs as an image sequence in the sequence editor I just see one layer.

Is it possible to see and edit all layers of the frames in the sequence editor too, and if yes how can I do it?

Whatever I tried I just got one layer of the three.
So acutally its not possible to make a video out of the frames because just one layer is rendered... and all the information from the other layers is missing.

EDIT:
I also tried to render the image in exr multilayer.
But there I just got a black image... and was not able to found any of the layers..

**EDIT 2:**
The workflow I tried so far:

1. I have many exr files
2. Open Blender and switch to Compositing
3. Open the Node editor and the VSE
4. Cleared all nodes and added an image node.
5. Opened all my exr files in the node as an image sequence
6. Added the Composite / Viewer nodes and activated the backdrop
7. Then this is what I get:

[image]

Sadly I just get one layer like mentioned before.. But directly after the rendering I have a picture will all three layers.
Like here:

[image]

With the green box I marked the missing layers.
With the orange one you can see how I made the layers before rendering.
As you can see in the EXR just the second layer (glass) is displayed.

I think maybe it's because the Render Layers node needs the scene.
And when I just import the EXRs I don't have the scene.

But is there a way to get the other layers in the EXRs after the rendering, when I have all images rendered?
I want to do the same like in the second picture (add filters and so on to the single layers) just *after* the rendering.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Load the EXR as an image sequence into the compositor of another scene. Route the layers that you want to the Compositor Output Node. Then load that scene as a strip into the VSE scene timeline. Do this for each layer of the EXR that you want to combine. Remember that in the VSE you will need to enable Linear to mix the EXR as they probably are not scene referred.

Make an EXR with multiple outputs:

[image: Export EXR]

Then import them into a compositor and route each layer to comp output using 1 scene per layer.

[image: EXR to VSE]

Then mix them as required in the VSE. The VSE isn't really ideal for this to be honest.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I root the layers to the output node? I already importet all the EXRs as an image sequence in the compositor. But from there I am not able to access the layers (I don't know how)... I just have the picture of one layer there... and if I insert the "render layer" node I can't choose the layers...

Comment: Are you sure that you saved the EXRs correctly? Have you seen any of the layers that you saved at all?

Comment: Yes I think so, but I'm not sure. If I stop during the rendering I can access the different layers of the last rendered image... but just of the last. So I can't use it for editing. Every single layer is rendered on its own. Is there a way to see if it's correctly saved? I tried to open it in Photoshop (without a plugin) and there I just see one layer too.

Comment: I have amended the answer, but I'm not sure why you would prefer to use the VSE for this task?

Comment: hmm maybe I made the layers wrong. I have an animation of a button with a light in it. So I made one layer which displays the button, and one that displays just the light... so that I can edit each of them separately after the rendering (in the VSE.. or is there a better option?). But to get the layers I used the tab right besides the rendering options...